# Proper use of escape characters in desktop file

Tags: quoting, escape-characters, .desktop

I have a command with a working .desktop Exec key as follows:

```
Exec=env XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/home/bean/.config/gedit/ gedit %U
```

I would like to use the `$HOME` variable instead and it works in the terminal but not when used in the .desktop file. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I assume this is because of improper "escape characters".

I have tried numerous variations of the command with `\` and `{}` but to no avail. After looking around I'm not even sure if what I want can be accomplished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no special characters there that you would need to escape, so no it's not an escaping issue. I just read through the freedesktop.org `.desktop` file [specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) and it does not explicitly mention environment variables, neither to allow nor disallow them. Nevertheless, neither `$HOME` nor `~` seem to be expanded in the `exec` field of a `.desktop` file.

So, it looks like what you're attempting is not possible.

Comment: Thank you, @terdon. I have been looking through examples of how other applications do it and they all seem to use absolute paths in the exec field.